# Enter '/' to exit a program in C

Tags: c, input, exit

I am stuck in an exercise. Whenever I enter a slash (`/`) in my input, the loop won't end.

Is it possible to check the input datatype? So that if it's number, then the `show()` executes. When it's `character('/')` then exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void show(int);

int main(){
    int quit = 0;

    printf("Enter a number to display: \n* times the input number\n");
    printf("Enter '/' to exit.\n");
    printf("======================\n\n");

    while(!quit) {
        printf("Input: ");
        int input;
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if (input == '/')
            quit = 1; // Suppose to exit when input = '/'
        else 
            show(input);

        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

void show(int n) {
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        printf("*");
}
```

Comment: Use char format specifier not int.

Comment: What you expect from `%d` scanf? It is for numeric value and `/` is invalid char in this case. Use `%c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error regarding the input type inside the while loop:

```
int input;
scanf("%d", &input);
```

Entering '/' here causes *undefined* behavior when it is asking for an int!

Instead, you have to let the input be a **string** (type `char *`), **check** whether the string equals ('/') either manually or through `strncmp(input, "/", 1)`, check if it represents an integer and then create **another int value** using `strtol(input, NULL, 10)` to convert to int if your input is valid and does not equal '/'.

Error checking can be involved (unfortunately), such as handling foreign characters, and verifying that your number is in the form of regex -?(\d) (single optional minus sign before numeric string).

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Now I can exit with '/', but show() broke. How do I convert my char* input into int so that show() will work?

Comment: I used atoi(n) - convert array string to int and exit the loop! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare against `'/'`, you should use a `char` variable, not an `int`. And so use `"%c"` as `scanf()`'s format string. Otherwise, `scanf()` won't read your `'/'` since it is not an integer.

This snippet will have the behavior you expect:

```
while (!quit) {
    char input;
    scanf("%c", &input);
    if (input == '/')
        quit = 1;
```

---

If you read a digit, then you can subtract the ASCII value of `0` (`48` or `'0'`) to your `char` so you will end up with its `int` equivalent:

```
show(input - '0');
show(input - 48);
```

Comment: Thanks! But this works only when the input is between 0-9.

Comment: Yes. If you want to input multiple characters, then you need to read a string. See the answer from @Mulliganaceous

Answer (score 1):

`%d` in `scanf` expects an `int` data type. When you enter `'/'`, it skips `'/'` and look for the `int` data type. It found nothing and this `'\'` is left in the buffer. In the next iteration it find the same `char` type and again skip this character and this cycle goes on causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%c` for a single character or `%s` for a string, `%d` is looking for a number.